# Keeping data in memory and persisting on Application_Disposed

Tags: asp.net, persistence

I'm building a website (for personal use, low load) and instead of using an Access or MySQL database for data storage I'm thinking of having one XML file that I load and parse on Application_Start and then keep in memory (in static objects). The website then do reads and writes against these in-memory objects and I will finally persist all data to the XML file on Application_Disposed.

I'm aware that I'll need to make reading/writing thread-safe, but besides that, does anyone see any problem using this approach?

Comment: Just use a  database, they're designed for this kind of thing.  I know  it's a small website but a database will make life a hell of a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I see a big problem: There are a number of reasons to why the whole application might die without you knowing about it, and without your data being saved to that xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was basically my biggest concern. However, besides the scenario where someone pulls the plug on the web server, when would the data NOT be persisted?

Comment: Hm, I see another problem: A new instance might be created before the old is shutdown to gracefully move "the request queue" to a new instance - your xml might be saved after the new one has loaded the (old) xml. Bluescreen will not execute application_end. Out of memory will neither. Bad code in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find Application_Dispose can get fired multiple times (so might don't be the best place to dispose your DI containers etc) whereas Application_End will only fires once (you can prove this by adding logging)

https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/561768-event-sequence

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

It seems VS2019 IIS Express doesn't seem to call Application_End as it should when you stop debugging, But IIS will.